# Properties of stochastic ordering

Tags: probability, statistics

On the entry for stochastic ordering in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering#Other_properties) it is stated that

> If $A\preceq B$ and ${\displaystyle {\rm {E}}[A]={\rm {E}}[B]}$ then ${\displaystyle A{\overset {d}{=}}B}$ (the random variables are equal in distribution).

My question is why do the random variables need to be equal in distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the layer cake representation of the expected value of $A$:
$$E[A]=\int_0^\infty 1-F_A(x)\,dx-\int_{-\infty}^0F_A(x)\,dx$$
Doing the same for $B$, and subtracting, 
$$E[B]-E[A]=\int_0^\infty F_A(x)-F_B(x)\,dx+\int_{-\infty}^0F_A(x)-F_B(x)\,dx=0,$$

or more simply, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_A(x)-F_B(x)\,dx=0
$$
Since $A\preceq B$, the integrand is nonnegative. It is also right continuous. The only right continuous, nonnegative function whose integral is zero is the zero function (why?). Therefore, $F_A(x)=F_B(x)$ for all $x$, so $A\stackrel{d}=B$.